# Is it ok to remove kernel-debug* on a production system if it's preventing upgrades? KVM template: /boot does not have enough space

Tags: centos6, yum, partition, boot, kernel

So there are legacy CentOS 6.x VPS templates on a very good host which are "stuck" with a 100mb /boot partition. Unfortunately since it was spawned ~4 years ago, one of our servers falls into this category. Short of changing zones to get a new package/template with more space, there is no way to increase the size of /boot. Switching zones would be quite a task since there would be new IP's and other schemas to re-do, so we are looking for alternatives.

We are using CloudLinux on that server, so perhaps the kernels are a bit bigger than normal. Either way we are forced to trim down active kernels to 1, which bothers me, but that is all that can fit into /boot. The problem is that there is a lack of space available to install new versions of the kernel.

Kernel-debug* packages seem to be larger than the standard kernel. **Is it safe to remove those? Are the debug kernels useful on production if there is an older version of a standard kernel [potentially] available for boot?**

This is a multi-tenant production VPS (KVM) running LAMP. We don't do much server side CLI on it, it's mostly ecom+webapps. It has kernelcare if that could provide some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With kernel-debug* you means both kernel-debug as well kernel-debuginfo as there is a difference between these two package

```
Kernel-debuginfo: Provides a executable image of the kernel with all the debug symbols

Kernel-debug: Enables some debugging code but not have same debug symbols on it 

### Excerpt from RedHat Doc ###


The kernel-debug enables the following options on the kernel that are disabled on the default kernel:

CONFIG_DEBUG_SLAB

Makes kernel do limited verification on memory allocation as well as    poisoning memory on free to catch use of freed memory. (performance impact mainly on kmalloc / mfree calls).
CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES

Allows mutexes semantics violations to be detected and reported.
CONFIG_DEBUG_RT_MUTEXES

Allows rt mutex semantics violations and rt mutex related deadlocks  (lockups) to be detected and reported automatically.
CONFIG_DEBUG_RWSEMS

Allows read-write semaphore semantics violations to be detected and reported.
CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC

This feature will check whether any held lock (spinlock, rwlock, mutex or rwsem) is incorrectly freed by the kernel, via any of the memory-freeing routines (kfree(), kmem_cache_free(), free_pages(), vfree(), etc), whether a live lock is incorrectly reinitialized via spin_lock_init(),mutex_init(),etc, or  whether there is any lock held during task exit.

CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING

This feature enables the kernel to prove that all locking that occurs in the kernel runtime is mathematically correct: that under no circumstance could an arbitrary (and not yet triggered) combination of observed locking sequences (on an arbitrary number of CPUs, running an arbitrary number of tasks and interrupt contexts) cause a deadlock.

CONFIG_DEBUG_VM

Turn on extended checks in the virtual memory system (performance impact).
 CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK

 Built SMP to catch missing spinlock initialization and certain other kinds  of spinlock errors commonly made. This is best used in conjunction with the NMI watchdog so that spinlock deadlocks are also debuggable.
CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK_SLEEP

Various routines which may sleep will become very noisy if they are called with a spinlock held.
 CONFIG_LOCK_STAT

Enables tracking lock contention points ( see /usr/share/doc/kernel-doc/Documentation/lockstat.txt ).
 CONFIG_XFS_DEBUG

 Enable XFS debugging features, including ASSERT checks, function wrappers around macros, and extra sanity-checking functions in various code paths (make a huge and slow code).
```

Now coming back to your question Is it safe to remove those?

These packages are only for debugging purpose and they could cause performance degradation..So yes they are safe to remove and only need to install during debugging.